# what is an example of `relative read` in C/C++ code leading to an information leak using pointers or shared_ptr ? (bypassing aslr stack)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

I am trying to code some examples of relative read vulnerable code leading me to leak addresses from stack or heap from XYZ process, in this case, my program will be coded in MSVS with some tweaks to achieve this, however, I am trying to use pointers or shared ptr instead of non-null terminator strings e.g. [image]

Comment: These concepts: _"...I am trying to use pointers or shared ptr instead of non-null terminator strings..."_ don't have much to do with each other.  This is making your question unclear to me.

Comment: I mean with examples of shared_ptr or wild pointers in this case

Comment: It's the _"...in this case..."_ part I am have trouble understanding.

Comment: I mean a relative read leaking address from stack or heap sections